# Bash script for checking a value against line of values in a file

Tags: bash

I have a script in Linux that will check a number inputted from the parameter. The number in this $status may vary. The script code after the is checking whether the code in $status is within a group of code or not. If yes, then echo "It exist". If not, then echo "Does not exist."

The problem is the group of code can change, and it's a pain to change the code conditional to reflect those changes. So I want to put all that group of numbers in a file.

For example:

The script `check.sh`:

```
$filecheck = "check.txt"
$status = $1
if [ $status EXISTS WITHIN $filecheck ]; then
  echo "It exists."
else
  echo "Does not exist."
fi
```

The `check.txt` contents:

```
201
5099
305
8670
2
582
9582
```

Run: `# ./check.sh 305`

Result: `It exists.`

Run: `# ./check.sh 689`

Result: `Does not exist.`

The question is, how should I formulate the conditional? I felt this should be not hard and involve grep, but I don't know how to formulate question about this in google to get the result I need, and I'm very beginner at bash script and Linux too. Actually the script is more than just this, but I only need the conditional part, so I simplified this down. Thanks.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use grep:

```
if grep -q "$1" "$filecheck" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "it exists"
else
    echo "it does not exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like a bash script but I think I got your question. You want to find if a given number exists in the list. To do that 'grep -w ...' should work for you, which looks for exact match. Note that it assumes that each number is on different line.

So your shell script would look like following:

```
filecheck="check.txt"
status=$1

grep -w $status $filecheck >/dev/null 2>&1 
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "It exists."
else
      echo "Does not exist."
fi
```

Comment: Great! Can I ask a little more? I know what `2>` means. But I don't know what `2>&1` means. And I see the other answer also use this as well. What is that?

Comment: It should be `>/dev/null 2>&1` in this answer. The `>/dev/null` says to send any standard output to /dev/null. The `2>&1` says to send and standard error output to the same place as standard output which we just set to /dev/null. If you get them backwards, you're sending stdout to null and stderr to the original stdout.

Comment: Thanks for the correction Harvey ... and that also answers Chen's question.